# Insert new record in custom object using visualforce pages

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a very simple Visualforce Page with using custom object called `employee__c`

I'm trying to save the data whatever the user have entered in the page, but I'm not getting any error from my below code but the page is blank not showing any input fields at all....

here is my VF page code:

```
<apex:page Controller="EmployeeController" >
  <!-- Page Header -->
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Employee Edit" subtitle="New Employee" />

  <!-- Begin Form -->
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Employee Informations" mode="edit"> 

      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="Information"> 
        <apex:inputField id="firstName" value="{!emp.First_Name__c}" required="true" />
        <apex:inputField id="lastName" value="{!emp.Last_Name__c}"  required="true" />     
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

my controller:

```
public with sharing class EmployeeController {

    public ApexPages.StandardController controller; 


    Public Employee__c emp = new Employee__c();
    public Employee__c getemp()
    {
        return emp;
    }

    Public String First_Name {get; set;}
    Public String Last_Name {get; set;}  


    public EmployeeController(ApexPages.StandardController Controller)
    {
        emp = (Employee__c)Controller.getRecord(); 
        this.controller=Controller;  
    } 
    public PageReference save() {
      insert emp; 
      return null;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Did you check the FLS and make sure the user has access to the fields?

Comment: Do you mean that the page heading and page block are shown but no field label or input areas are shown at all when the page is initially opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the field level security is set to editable for your profile. Also you should have create permission on Employee object to create records

Comment: can you expand your answer little bit more so other might benefit from it, like how do you go after FLS and how do you create permission on the object

Comment: go to your object details page. click on First_Name__c-> select edit field level security. select all the profiles.